# Kivy: return to home screen on inactivity or button push?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have an application with multiple screens (using ScreenManager), and would like to return to the home screen from any of the other screens: either on >30s inactivity, or on the click of a 'home' button.

**Button:**
I could add a button to every screen in my .kv file, and bind the following on_press method:

```
on_press:
    screen_manager.transition.direction = 'left'
    screen_manager.transition.duration = 0.5
    screen_manager.current = 'main_screen'
```

Is there a better way to add a button on all screens, rather than repeating this on every screen? This would also require me to make sure the button is on the exact same position on each screen.

**Automatic check:**
When on a screen, is there a way to check how long the screen has not been touched, and if that time is more than 30s then call the method from the button above?

I try to split my graphic code in the .kv file and the code logic in the python file, so I am happy with answers involving both.
Thanks a lot for any pointers, eager to learn more kivy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom button just for that purpose in your `kv` file:

```
<MyReturnButton@Button>:
    text: 'Return'
    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'y':0}
    size_hint: None, None
    size: self.texture_size
    on_press:
        screen_manager.transition.direction = 'left'
        screen_manager.transition.duration = 0.5
        screen_manager.current = 'main_screen'
```

Then, just add:

```
MyReturnButton:
```

To the `kv` rule for any screen where you want that `Button`. Of course, the `size`, `pos_hint`, and any other properties can be set to your choice.

As for the automatic screen change, you can use `Clock.schedule_once` to set a timer in the `on_enter` method of  `Screen`, and use the `on_touch_down` method to reset the timer:

```
def callbackTo2(*args):
    screen_manager.current = 'main_screen'

class ScreenOne(Screen):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(ScreenOne, self).__init__(name='ScreenOne')
        self.timer = None

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        print('on_enter ScreenOne:')
        # start the timer for 30 seconds
        self.timer = Clock.schedule_once(callbackTo2, 30)

    def on_leave(self, *args):
        # cancel the timer
        self.timer.cancel()
        self.timer = None

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.timer is not None:
            self.timer.cancel()
        # reset the timer
        self.timer = Clock.schedule_once(callbackTo2, 30)
        return super(ScreenOne, self).on_touch_down(touch)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @John, this seems to be what I need. However when I define the on_press action in the custom button, I get a name error `NameError: name 'screen_manager' is not defined`. I have read that this is something to do with my id for the Screen Manager not having yet been initialized by the time this button definition is read. It seems to be true, since the same on_press action works if I write it in each screen separately. Do you know how I could get around that withour re-writing on_press everytime?

Comment: I was wondering where you defined `screen_manager`. That is why we usually ask for a [mcve]. One way to solve this would be to access the `screen_manager` id through some path. Not knowing the structure of your `App` makes it impossible to predict what that path might be. On the `kv` file that path might start with something like `app.get_running_App()`. Another way would be to create a method (perhaps called `return_to_main_screen`) in your `App` class, and then reference that as `app.return_to_main_screen()` in `kv` or `App.get_running_app().return_to_main_screen()` in `Python` code.

Comment: Clear. Sorry for the missing example, my bad, but this solves it, many thanks for your help!